# como pudiera regresar los valores con los if

Tags: javascript, html, variables, condiciones

tengo el codigo que el usuario ingresa 3 valores por medio de inputs y realizan una operancion difenrente cada mes entonces se realizan 12 operaciones pero despues de las 12 operacion el resultado tiene que pasar por algunas condiciones de dependeran del resultado de los 3 inputs iniciales entonces estos if tengo que hacer cada cuenta en cada mes pero para poderlo realizar en cada mes nesesito que el de enero este bien pero no recuerdo muy bien como terminar el if para que haga la operacion y que te imprima solo el valor que cumple el if, pero como puedo hacer que los if funcionen y cuando quito las condiciones si funciona la primera parte pero si los pongo ya no funciona

```js
 
   


        <script>
 
 var enero = 1;
  var enero1 = 0.793;
  var enero2 = 0.956;
  var enero3 = 2.802;
  var febrero = 2;
  var febrero1 = 0.793;
  var febrero2 = 0.956;
  var febrero3 = 2.802;
  var marzo = 3;
  var marzo1 = 0.793;
  var marzo2 = 0.956;
  var marzo3 = 2.802;
  var abril = 4;
  var abril1 = 0.793;
  var abril2 = 0.956;
  var abril3 = 2.802;
  var mayo = 5;
  var mayo1 = 0.569;
  var mayo2 = 0.718;
  var mayo3 = 1.727;
  var mayo4 = 2.745;
  var junio = 6;
  var junio1 = 0.569;
  var junio2 = 0.718;
  var junio3 = 1.727;
  var junio4 = 2.745;
  var julio = 7;       
  var julio1 = 0.569;
  var julio2 = 0.718;
  var julio3 = 1.727;
  var julio4 = 2.745;
  var agosto = 8;
  var agosto1 = 0.569;
  var agosto2 = 0.718;
  var agosto3 = 1.727;
  var agosto4 = 2.745;
  var septiembre = 9;
  var septiembre1 = 0.569;
  var septiembre2 = 0.718;
  var septiembre3 = 1.727;
  var septiembre4 = 2.745;
  var octubre = 10;
  var octubre1 = 0.569;
  var octubre2 = 0.718;
  var octubre3 = 1.727;
  var octubre4 = 2.745;
  var noviembre = 11;
  var noviembre1 = 0.793;
  var noviembre2 = 0.956;
  var noviembre3 = 2.802;
  var diciembre = 12;
  var diciembre1 = 0.793;
  var diciembre2 = 0.956;
  var diciembre3 = 2.802; 



function calc() {
  var a = document.getElementById("a").value; 
  var b = document.getElementById("b").value; 
  var c = document.getElementById("c").value; 

  var result1 = document.getElementById("result1");
  var result2 = document.getElementById("result2");
  var result3 = document.getElementById("result3");
  var result4 = document.getElementById("result4");
  var result5 = document.getElementById("result5");
  var result6 = document.getElementById("result6");
  var result7 = document.getElementById("result7");
  var result8 = document.getElementById("result8");
  var result9 = document.getElementById("result9");
  var result10 = document.getElementById("result10");
  var result11 = document.getElementById("result11");
  var result12 = document.getElementById("result12");

  result1.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*enero));
  result2.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)*febrero));
  result3.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* marzo));
  result4.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* abril));
  result5.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* mayo));
  result6.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* junio));
  result7.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* julio));
  result8.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* agosto));
  result9.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* septiembre));
  result10.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* octubre));
  result11.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* noviembre));
  result12.value = parseInt(a) - (parseInt(b)*(1.224/250*parseInt(c)* diciembre));
}


if (result1<76) {
      function enerno1 () {
          
         return(0.793 * result1);
      }  
      }
      if (result1 < 201 ) {
        function enero2 () {
          
          return(0.793 * 75 +(result1 - 75)* 0.956)* 1.16;
        }
      } else {
        function enero3 (){
        return((0.793 * 75+(125* 0.956)+ result1- 200)*2.802) * 1.16;

      } 
        
      }
```

```html
<input id="a" type="number" value="0">
      <input id="b" type="number" value="0">
      <input id="c" type="number" value="0"><br>
      <h1>invierno</h1>
      <output id="result1"></output><br>
      <output id="result2"></output><br>
      <output id="result3"></output><br>
      <output id="result4"></output><br>
      <output id="result11"></output><br>
      <output id="result12"></output><br>
      <h1>verano</h1>
      <output id="result5"></output><br>
      <output id="result6"></output><br>
      <output id="result7"></output><br>
      <output id="result8"></output><br>
      <output id="result9"></output><br>
      <output id="result10"></output><br>
```

Comment: Viendo tu [pregunta anterior](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264357/nesesito-ayuda-para-realizar-los-if) y esta, no logro entender el porqué eres tan repetitivo con las cosas. Veo que los meses de Noviembre hasta Abril tienen los mismos valores, igual sucede con el resto de meses. Los divides en 6 meses de verano y 6 de invierno (imagino que te encuentras en un país tropical). Luego tus condicionales `if` tienen problemas de `bound` o límites. Ya por allí es un error bastante grave. Por último, y no menos importante, tus funciones no las llamas nunca. Hay mucho por arreglar. Saludos

Comment: Además tu pregunta tiene muchos problemas de redacción, empezando que en tu formulación da la pregunta sólo hay una coma. Eso dificulta mucho entender las ideas que deseas expresar. No está claro el objetivo que deseas alcanzar, tampoco explicas qué debe realizar cada función y lo que deseas obtener. Si crees que puedes mejorar tu pregunta, te invito a hacer clic en [edit] y realizar la correcciones necesarias. Saludos